# Função "extract()" não funciona dentro do laço foreach

Tags: php

**Tenho o seguinte código:**

```
<?php
        $dados = array(
            "carro" => 'Ford Focus',
            "ano" => 2007
            );


        foreach($dados as $carros):

            extract($carros);           

        endforeach;
```

?>

**O problema:**

Se eu informo o `extract($dados)` fora do `foreach`, ele cria as variáveis com os nomes dos índices do `array` `$dados`, e com seus respectivos valores.

Porém, se eu ponho o `extract($carros)` dentro do laço foreach, ele me retorna um aviso de que eu preciso informar um `array` no `extract`, e que eu informei uma `string`, e também, se eu chamar a variável `$carros` ou `$ano`, retorna `undefined variable`.

Alguém pode me ajudar aqui?

Comment: pq você precisa do `extract()`?

Comment: Vou usar no carregamento de templates html.  O foreach vai subtituir links nos tpl's, pelos nomes das variáveis vindas do extract.  As variáveis e os links precisam ter o mesmo nome, pois isso vai virar uma função dinâmica, onde o php substitui automaticamente o link no tpl pela variável de mesmo nome, sem que eu precise setar manualmente.

Comment: `foreach($dados as $k => $v){ extract($dados[$k]);}` isso dá o resultado desejado?

Comment: Não, o erro persiste.

Comment: Fazer o `foreach` e `extract` em cada valor "produziria" o mesmo resultado que o usar o `extract` no array. Não entendi qual é o objetivo disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php), do PHP, tem a seguinte sintaxe:

```
int extract ( array $var_array [, int $extract_type [, string $prefix ]] )
```

Parâmetros:

**$var_array**: uma variável do tipo *array* associativo. Para cada par chave/valor, a função `extract` cria, no contexto atual, uma variável de nome igual a chave e valor igual ao valor. Isso ocorre importando tais variáveis à tabela de símbolos corrente, ou seja, se uma variável já existir com o mesmo nome, será sobrescrita.

**extract_type**: Forma como serão validadas e/ou tratadas as novas variáveis:

```
EXTR_OVERWRITE
    Se houver uma colisão, sobrescreve a variável existente. 

EXTR_SKIP
    Se houver uma colisão, não sobrescreve a variável existente. 

EXTR_PREFIX_SAME
    Se houver uma colisão, adiciona um prefixo ao nome da variável 
    definido pelo argumento prefix. 

EXTR_PREFIX_ALL
    Adiciona um prefixo ao nome de todas as variáveis definido por prefix.

EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID
    Adiciona um prefixo definido por prefix apenas para variáveis como 
    nomes inválidos ou numéricos. 

EXTR_IF_EXISTS
    Só sobrescreve a variável se ela já existe na tabela de símbolos 
    corrente, caso contrário, não faz nada. Isso é útil quando se quer 
    definir uma lista de variáveis válidas e então extrair só as que 
    foram definidas em $_REQUEST, por exemplo. 

EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS
    Só cria nomes de variáveis usando o prefixo se na tabela de símbolos
    já existe uma variável com o nome sem esse prefixo. 

EXTR_REFS
    Extrai variáveis como referências, ou seja, os valores das variáveis
    importadas ainda estarão referenciando os valores do parâmetro 
    var_array. Essa opção pode ser usada sozinha ou em conjunto com as 
    outras usando o operador 'ou' em extract_type.
```

Se extract_type não for especificado, é assumido o valor EXTR_OVERWRITE.

**prefix**: Note que prefix só é necessário se `extract_type` for `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME`, `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`, `EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID` ou `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS`. Se o nome com o prefixo não for um nome de variável válido, ela não será importada para a tabela de símbolos. Prefixos são automaticamente separados da chave do array pelo caractere underscore.

**Retorna** um valor inteiro referente ao número de variáveis importadas com sucesso para a tabela de símbolo.

A grosso modo, pode-se dizer que o equivalente da função é:

```
$data = [
    "carro" => "Fiat Uno",
    "ano" => "2017"
];

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    ${$key} = $value;
}

echo $carro; // Fiat Uno
echo $ano;   // 2017
```

Chamar a função `extract` para os valores do array, como tentou fazer, não faz sentido algum. Agora, você falou em substituir os valores no template. Pelo o que eu entendi, você teria um template como:

```
$template = "Meu carro é {{carro}}, ano {{ano}}";
```

Sendo que `{{carro}}` e `{{ano}}` seriam substituídos pelos valores nas variáveis. Se for isso, podes fazer algo como:

```
function parse ($template, array $vars)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('#{{(.*?)}}#', function($match) use ($vars) {
        extract($vars);
        return ${$match[1]};
   }, $template);
}
```

E fazendo:

```
echo parse($template, $data);
```

Teríamos a saída: `Meu carro é Fiat Uno, ano 2017`.

> **Nota**: Não deve ser a melhor maneira de se fazer isso, só exemplifiquei tentando compreender se é essa a sua necessidade. Até porque o `extract` nem seria necessário nesta função, pois poderia retornar o valor direto do array `$data`.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/FlUz/1), no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/tf5kAd) e no [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/da92a88e4948935bae01b69fd4b448d3).